# only 1 cmd working at a time - Discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext.commands import Cog
from discord.ext.commands import command, has_permissions, has_role
import sqlite3
from mcstatus import JavaServer
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

  
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    if message.content.startswith('$help'):
        [some radom embed no error here]
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed) 
      
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$status'):
        a = message.content.split(" ", 1)
        ip = a[1] #channel_ID
        server = JavaServer.lookup(ip)
        status = server.status()
        #print(f"The server has {status.players.online} players ")
        await message.channel.send(status.players.online ) 
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Bpth the commands is not working at same time pls help me to fix it out
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3unc.png)
no response for 1st cmd
$help
$status mc.hypixel.net
Player Counter Beta
BOT
— Today at 9:24 PM
64162

Comment: You've defined two functions with the same name, so the latest one defined overrides the other.

Comment: @SKGokulbarath, just copy-paste the code of one function into the other, and delete the empty function. It would work as-is, but you'd want to replace the second `if` with `elif`. I suggest you learn the basics of Python before working with libraries like discord.py.

Comment: Using `commands` would be better here. Also be aware (not a *huge* issue) that your server status is synchronous and can block the other async things going in discord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define `commands` instead of listening to an `event`.

```
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
     embed = discord.Embed()
     await ctx.send(embed=embed)
      
@client.command()
async def status(ctx):
      a = message.content.split(" ", 1)
      ip = a[1] #channel_ID
      server = JavaServer.lookup(ip)
      status = server.status()
      await ctx.send(status.players.online)
```

Comment: Important note: in order to use commands, you need to instantiate your client as an instance of [`discord.ext.commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) instead of `discord.Client`.

Comment: How can I add  @ Has_permission here

Comment: When I added it was not working

Comment: Try using `@commands.has_permissions()` to check for permissions.

Comment: Can I get your discord ID?

Comment: Sure its Conner Wolf 08#9758

Answer (score 1):

[Conner Wolf 08's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73352746/12975140) is the preferred method. Just for the sake of completeness, if you wanted to do this with `Client` as you currently are, without using `commands.Bot`, you'd want to check for both prefixes in the same function, as [The Amateur Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16136190/the-amateur-coder) suggested in the comments.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$help'):
        [some radom embed no error here]
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
    elif message.content.startswith('$status'):
        a = message.content.split(" ", 1)
        ip = a[1] #channel_ID
        server = JavaServer.lookup(ip)
        status = server.status()
        #print(f"The server has {status.players.online} players ")
        await message.channel.send(status.players.online )
```